# Как скачать файл через прокси Python?

Tags: python

Как собственно скачать файл через прокси HTTP/SOCKS4/SOCKS5 на питоне?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример, как можно файл скачать через socks5-прокси на Питоне 3 без monkey-patching `socket` модуля:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import urllib.request
import socks  # $ pip install PySocks
from sockshandler import SocksiPyHandler  # from pysocks


socks_port = 9050  # tor socks5 port
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(
    SocksiPyHandler(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, "localhost", socks_port)
)
urllib.request.install_opener(opener) #NOTE: global for the process

urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, filename)
```

Можно не устанавливать `opener`, чтобы другие соединения в том же процессе не затрагивать, а использовать его напрямую: `opener.open(url)`.

---

Для http-прокси, также можно `build_opener()` использовать:

```
from urllib.request import ProxyHandler, build_opener

opener = build_opener(ProxyHandler(dict(http='host:port')))
```

Comment: Нету модуля build opener у urllib3.reqest

Comment: Все заработало, это я оказывается тупил

Answer (score 1):

```
import socks
import socket
import urllib2
socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS4, proxyHost, proxyPort)
socket.socket = socks.socksocket
urllib2.urlopen(URL)
```

Например вот так. Модуль socks - SocksiPy

Comment: Вместо SocksiPy порекомендую PySocks как актуальное и более допиленное

Comment: Это на какой питон? на линуксе сижу через синаптик поставил на 2 питоне не пашет

Comment: @Thread 2.6, 2.7 Как именно не работает-то?

Comment: уже все, заработало как поставил PySocks но теперь идет билд и заканчивается без ошибки

Comment: Все работает это я оказывается тупил!