# Использование сети tor без клиента

Tags: http, сеть, tor

Можно ли как-то отправлять http запросы и получать ответы от сервера  пропуская трафик через сеть tor, но без использования tor клиента? Например отправить post запрос на сайт, не через браузер а просто по http протоколу, но через сеть tor, а затем получить ответ?

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Как скачать файл через прокси Python?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/523568/23044)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно работать с TOR через библиотеки, которые есть для всех популярных языков программирования. К примеру следующий код для python.

```
from TorCtl import TorCtl
import urllib2

user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.7) Gecko/2009021910 Firefox/3.0.7'
headers={'User-Agent':user_agent}

def request(url):
    def _set_urlproxy():
        proxy_support = urllib2.ProxyHandler({"http" : "127.0.0.1:8118"})
        opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_support)
        urllib2.install_opener(opener)
    _set_urlproxy()
    request=urllib2.Request(url, None, headers)
    return urllib2.urlopen(request).read()

def renew_connection():
    conn = TorCtl.connect(controlAddr="127.0.0.1", controlPort=9051, passphrase="your_password")
    conn.send_signal("NEWNYM")
    conn.close()

for i in range(0, 10):
    renew_connection()
    print request("http://icanhazip.com/")
```

Answer (score 0):

Да, собственно TOR выступает как прокси (SOCKS или даже HTTP). Подключаетесь к нему и работаете.